# Crystal Reports changing logon info at runtime doesn't work C#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, database-connection

I know there is a problem with this, as I found many threads about this, but nothing worked for me and I'm getting crazy !

I have to change logon informations when I generate my report.
But the ApplyLogOnInfo method always brings back the bad data.
I try to connect to an ODBC MySQL database.

Here is my code :

```
ReportDocument myReport = new ReportDocument();
myReport.Load("myReportPath");

ParameterField myParamFieldId = myReport.ParameterFields["param1"];
ParameterDiscreteValue param = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
param.Value = "param1";
myParamFieldId.CurrentValues.Add(param);

ParameterField myParamFieldNumRevision = myReport.ParameterFields["param2"];
ParameterDiscreteValue paramNumRevision = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
param.Value = "param2";
myParamFieldNumRevision.CurrentValues.Add(param);

ApplyLogOnInfo(myReport);

try
{
    myReport.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, true, "Rapport");
    myReport.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
finally
{
    myReport.Dispose();
}


private void ApplyLogOnInfo(ReportDocument rpt)
{
    ConnectionInfo connInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
    connInfo.ServerName = "test";
    connInfo.DatabaseName = "test";
    connInfo.UserID = "test";
    connInfo.Password = "test";
    connInfo.Type = ConnectionInfoType.CRQE;
    connInfo.IntegratedSecurity = false;

    foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table table in rpt.Database.Tables)
    {
        TableLogOnInfo logonInfo = table.LogOnInfo;
        logonInfo.ConnectionInfo = connInfo;
        table.ApplyLogOnInfo(logonInfo); // Here, old values are brought back
    }


    // Idem on Sub-reports
    foreach (ReportDocument sousRpt in rpt.Subreports)
    {
        ReportDocument rptSub = rpt.OpenSubreport(sousRpt.Name);
        foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table table in rptSub.Database.Tables)
        {
            TableLogOnInfo logonInfo = table.LogOnInfo;
            logonInfo.ConnectionInfo = connInfo;
            table.ApplyLogOnInfo(logonInfo);
        }
    }
}
```

I saw that this could be due to sub-reports and parameters. No way to get this to work.

I tried also:

```
rpt.DataSourceConnections[0].SetConnection("test", "test", "test", "test");
// But DataSourceConnections[0].Attributes and DataSourceConnections[0].LogonProperties still store values from the old connection, and doesn't work. I tried to clear it does'nt apply.

// I tried to pass parameters like this
myReport.SetParameterValue("param1", "test");
myReport.SetParameterValue("param1", "test");

// I tried with dataset and fill method
```

Well now I'm stuck, and really need your help !! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is months later and you may have solved it.  In upgrading our Crystal Reports from 2008 to 2012, I noticed there were issues with how we were passing parameters and login credentials.  Overall, everything was not working as I had hoped.

I decided it was best to write a new function that was compatible in both 2008 and 2012, and was overall more flexible.  It takes the viewer, source, report path, and parameters to load it all up.

I just started using this in our Production environment for 2008 for a couple reports with great results.  I would suggest you modify it a bit further if it does not work exactly as you may have hoped for sub-reports that may or may not come from a different ODBC login credentials.

```
    public void LoadCrystalReportViewer(CrystalReportViewer crystalReportViewer, CrystalReportSource crystalReportSource, string reportFilePath, Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
    {
        crystalReportSource.ReportDocument.FileName = reportFilePath;
        crystalReportSource.ReportDocument.Load(reportFilePath);
        crystalReportSource.ReportDocument.Database.Tables[0].LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = "PASSWORD";
        crystalReportSource.ReportDocument.Database.Tables[0].ApplyLogOnInfo(crystalReportSource.ReportDocument.Database.Tables[0].LogOnInfo);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> parameter in parameters)
        {
            if (crystalReportSource.ReportDocument.ParameterFields[parameter.Key] != null)
            {
                crystalReportSource.ReportDocument.SetParameterValue(parameter.Key, parameter.Value);
            }
        }

        crystalReportSource.EnableCaching = true;
        crystalReportSource.CacheDuration = 300;
        crystalReportViewer.ReportSource = crystalReportSource;
        crystalReportViewer.ReuseParameterValuesOnRefresh = true;
        crystalReportViewer.EnableParameterPrompt = false;
        crystalReportViewer.LogOnInfo.Add(crystalReportSource.ReportDocument.Database.Tables[0].LogOnInfo);

        foreach (ParameterField parameterField in crystalReportViewer.ParameterFieldInfo)
        {
            parameterField.DefaultValues = crystalReportSource.ReportDocument.ParameterFields[parameterField.Name].CurrentValues;
        }

        crystalReportViewer.Visible = true;
    }
```